# Where can I find a list of the components included by default with Blazor?

Tags: components, blazor

I am just beginning to learn Blazor, and my google-fu seems to be failing me here. From what I understand, Blazor includes certain components by default (`EditForm` for instance). I would like to know which components are available to me.

The problem is, when I google `blazor components` I end up with a whole slew of third party component packages, some free and some free until you actually want to use them.

Where would I find a canonical list of the components that are available in a standard Blazor installation so that I can learn them before I decide to bring in any third party dependencies into my project?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those components come form Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components, which are imported in `_Imports.razor` :

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Routing
```

You can find a list at:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.forms?view=aspnetcore-3.1

and

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Answer (score 1):

The Blazor framework is component based. 
[Here is the link to the framework.](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/tree/master/src/Components). I always consult these libraries which constitutes the Blazor framework. [Here's the url for the Forms components](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/tree/master/src/Components/Web/src/Forms).
There are other libraries with many other components, as for instance, components for authentication, authorization, validation, etc. Of course I wouldn't suggest you to start learning from these libraries, but to use them for reference. Though I must admit that I've learned Blazor from those libraries, and github issues, but it was from the very beginning. I've never used other web sites, and I know nothing about third party components. It's too early, and I prefer to concentrate on the framework itself. 
I'd suggest you to start learning Blazor from the docs, they have a couple of samples, which I recommend to learn, and I can also suggest that you read the articles by chriss chianty(search for his web site).

Good luck...

Comment: Yes, as you have suggested, I am avoiding third party libraries as far as possible. Chris Sainty is an excellent source for information. This particular link has been quite useful for me. https://chrissainty.com/3-ways-to-communicate-between-components-in-blazor/